# Will Ubuntu Touch at ZTE Grand X IN?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is it possible to use Ubuntu Touch on ZTE Grand X IN? It works with an Intel Atom Z2460.
I ask because at main page is written something about Ubuntu Touch and Intel Atom. I am a developer and I want to know more.

Thanks for your answer.